# Interview: How verify one string is include another string?

Tags: algorithm

General idea is that do two for loop, carry out every character from string 1, compare to every character from string2, if all finded, that will indicate Include.
so we need to loop all the char from string1, and compare all look all the character from string2, that will O sqaure runing time.
Which interviewer says it is not good idea.

after it, i am thinking for it. i cannot generate one idea that did not do two loop.
perhaps i can first get all the character from string1, convert into asc2, the number built into a tree. so when do the compare to the string2, it will make search very fast.

Or any folk has better idea?

Like string1 is abc but string2 is cbattt that means every character is included in string2.
not substring,

Comment: What is `asc2`? Also define what exactly "one string includes another" means.

Comment: sorry ......asc...normal string, does not matter

Comment: And what is inlcude? Do you mean that one string contains all the character from another? Or contains it as a substring?

Comment: Count characters in the target string and fill 26-items hash. Where key represents character and value represents occurrences count. Then iterate over each character of a lookup string and subtract one from the correspondent item. End if the string ends or you get negative value after subtraction. `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

as iccthedral says, [boyer moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) is probably what the interviewer was looking for.

Comment: sorry , is not substring, i mean every character in string1 should include in string2. actually i get idea(but didnot know whether best) is first sort then compare

Comment: can i ask where you got some questions, i  just want to do more practices. career cup seems more harder ones.

Comment: You'd do better with Google translate to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

searching a text for a given pattern (pattern matching) is a very known problem. known solutions:

1. [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)
2. [witness table](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~amir/PMslides/pattern_matching_lecture_notes_2.pdf)
3. [boyer-moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)
4. [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)

all solutions vary in some minor aspects, like if it can be generalized for 2D pattern matching, or more. if it needs pre-processing, if it can be generalized for unbound alphabet, running time, etc'...

**EDIT:**
if you just want to know if all the letters of some string appear in some other string, why not use a table the size of your alphabet, indicating if a given char can be found in the string. if the alphabet is unbounded or extremely large (more than *O(1)*), use hash table.

Comment: i wouldn't. boyer-moore cannot be generalized (as far as i know) for more than 1D. i would probably use a witness table for that.